# What Minecraft tag do I give to a post when editing if I do not know which edition it is?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

So I was editing someone else's question [(this one)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401823/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-in-minecraft-chat) to try and un-close it, and I removed its only tag as it was not relevant. It would not let me post it without a tag, so I thought of adding a Minecraft tag. The thing is, the user did not specify the minecraft edition, so I just went with Minecraft Java Edition. This could be mitigated by introducing an "unknown-minecraft-edition" tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have enough information to meaningfully edit the question, therefore the best course of action not to edit the question at all. The question needs a lot of improvement and the only person that can provide the information needed for those improvements is the original asker.

As an example, the question is extremely broad, but we are unable to narrow the focus without potentially changing the intent of the original question.  Such an edit would also be rejected unless it came from the asker.

The reality is a lot of the time we can only help people who choose to help themselves first.  That is what this asker must do.

Answer (score 3):

An "unknown game" tag would not be valid.

Tags aren't meant to be used in this manner. They are meant to be used to identify the exact game you are playing, or what your question is about (for example, the [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag would be used typically for questions asking for help running a game).

You probably saw your [first edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/322383) was rejected.  This is because you tagged it with two versions of Minecraft (Java and Bedrock).  This is invalid because it's tagging multiple editions of the game. It should only be one.

Even if you tagged it with *one* of these tags, it still be invalid because it would be at best, an assumption of what version the original poster is playing. We really need the original poster to make an edit to their post to identify the version of the game they are playing, because only they can definitively state so.

Comment: Can't you just add the "minecraft" tag back?

Comment: @Lalala we need the original poster to make an edit to their post and specify which version of Minecraft it is.  We can't do that for them, as it would be an assumption.  If the poster never makes this edit, the post will remain closed and eventually be automatically deleted.

Comment: @Lalala Re-adding `minecraft` would be moot. The tag was nuked years ago to remove the discrepancy between the java edition and bedrock edition. This was because answers between the two were often drastically different